# Rails Save Hash in Model Attribute Submitted by Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, simple-form, strong-parameters

I am building a Rails5 app where I have a model `Training` with an attribute `participant_ratings`, a hash which should hold the ratings of all participants assigned to the training in the way `participant.id => rating value`. I already managed to build the form for submitting the hash.

```
<%= simple_form_for @training do |f| %> 
...
  <div id="ratings-container" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
    <%= f.label t('trainings._form.ratings') %>
    <% Participant.all.order(:name).each do |p| %>
      <span class="checkbox_container">
        <% current_rating = @training.participant_ratings[p.id].nil? ? '' : @training.participant_ratings[p.id] %>
        <label id='star<%= "#{p.id}" %>' data-rating='<%= "#{current_rating}" %>' style="margin-bottom: 12px;" ></label>
        <input id="rating<%= "#{p.id}" %>" name="participant_ratings[<%= "#{p.id}" %>]" type="hidden" value="<%= "#{@training.participant_ratings[p.id]}" %>" />
      </span>
      <script>
        $('#star<%= "#{p.id}" %>').raty({
            score: function() {
                return $(this).attr('data-rating');
            },
            half  : true,
            readOnly: <%= !@training.participants.include?(p) %>,
            path: '/assets',
            click : function(score, evt) {
                $('#rating<%= "#{p.id}" %>').val(score);
            }
        });
        $('#training_participant_ids_<%= "#{p.id}" %>').change(function () {
            var star = $('#star<%= "#{p.id}" %>');
            if(document.getElementById('training_participant_ids_<%= "#{p.id}" %>').checked) {
                star.raty('readOnly', false);
            } else {
                star.raty('cancel');
                star.raty('readOnly', true);
                $('#rating<%= "#{p.id}" %>').val("");
            }
        })
      </script>
    <% end %>
  </div>   
...
<% end %>
```

I can see that the hash is sent correctly to the server:
`"participant_ratings"=>{"3"=>"5", "1"=>"3.5", "2"=>""}`

But I cannot manage this hash to be saved in the `Training`s attribute. I get the error:
`Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a ActionController::Parameters. -- <ActionController::Parameters {"3"=>"5", "1"=>"3.5", "2"=>""} permitted: false>`

My controller code:

```
class TrainingsController < BaseController
...
  def update
    @training = Training.find(params[:id])
    @training.updated_date_time = DateTime.now
    @training.participant_ratings = params[:participant_ratings]

    if @training.update(training_params)
      flash[:notice] = t('flash.training.updated')
      redirect_to @training
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def training_params
      params.require(:training).permit(:village, :topic, :user_id, :start_time, :end_time, {:participant_ids => []}, :participant_ratings)
    end
end
```

My `Training` class:

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord
...

  serialize :participant_ratings, Hash

...
end
```

What do I have to change to save the hash in the `participant_ratings` attribute in my `Training` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, (as pointed out by Dmitry Kukhlevsky), I had to make sure that the `participants_rating`-hash was *inside* the `training`-hash when submitted by my form, so I had to change the name attribute in my hidden form input for the rating:

```
<input id="rating<%= "#{p.id}" %>" name="training[participant_ratings][<%= "#{p.id}" %>]" type="hidden" value="<%= "#{@training.participant_ratings[p.id]}" %>" />
```

Secondly, I had to whitelist the keys for my `participant_ratings`-hash so that they are permitted:

```
def training_params
  ratings_keys = params[:training].try(:fetch, :participant_ratings, {}).keys
  params.require(:training).permit(:village, :topic, :user_id, :start_time, :end_time, {:participant_ids => []}, participant_ratings: ratings_keys )
end
```

I found this solution in [this rails thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454)

After that `participant_ratings` was saved just fine!

Still thanks a lot to Dmitry for all his help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@training.participant_ratings = params[:participant_ratings].to_hash
```

But i think storing it as json will be even better, so:

```
@training.participant_ratings = params[:participant_ratings].to_json
```

And then to read it as a hash:

```
hash = JSON.parse(@training.participant_ratings)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and the error message doesn't show up anymore but still no values are stored to my `participant_ratings` hash. I tried to call update on that as well or to call save on my `@training` but nothing happens. I also tried to define `participant_ratings` as a hash in the `trainings_params` method: `params.require(:training).permit(:village, :topic, :user_id, :start_time, :end_time, {:participant_ids => []}, {:participant_ratings => {}} )` but still no values are saved. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated! It feels so close to the solution! ;)

Comment: I think it should be simply params.require(:training).permit(:village, ....  , :participant_ratings).   What is your database field type for :participant_ratings?

Comment: if you use serialize, it should be TEXT not STRING

Comment: my database field type is TEXT here: `t.text     "participant_ratings"` and I changed my `training_params` method back to `... :participant_ratings` but still no success... :( I can see that `updated_date_time` is saved, so why isn't `participant_ratings`?

Comment: `updated_date_time` value is set in the line before the setting of `participant_ratings` in the `update` method in my trainings_controller

Comment: Do you see "Unpermitted params" notice in console log?

Comment: Could you post the request log from terminal?

Comment: Started PATCH "/trainings/3" for ::1 at 2017-01-30 13:24:01 +0100
Processing by TrainingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1R3sINy89CazPpmq+lFOQwpF4gnza0vz2ChNruJx09639ByrLf+h2zekwm7DC8QvjqWqPnjYj+m4akFp0bM9HA==", "training"=>{"topic"=>"fthfgh", "village"=>"fghfgh", "user_id"=>"2", "start_time(1i)"=>"2017", "start_time(2i)"=>"1", "start_time(3i)"=>"26", "start_time(4i)"=>"15", "start_time(5i)"=>"52", "end_time(1i)"=>"2017", "end_time(2i)"=>"1", "end_time(3i)"=>"26", "end_time(4i)"=>"15", "end_time(5i)"=>"52", "participant_ids"=>["", "3", "1"]}, ...

Comment: "score"=>"", "participant_ratings"=>{"3"=>"5", "1"=>"1", "2"=>""}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Training Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "trainings".* FROM "trainings" WHERE "trainings"."id" = ? ORDER BY "trainings"."start_time" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Participant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" IN (3, 1)

Comment: Participant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" INNER JOIN "participants_trainings" ON "participants"."id" = "participants_trainings"."participant_id" WHERE "participants_trainings"."training_id" = ?  [["training_id", 3]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)

Comment: UPDATE "trainings" SET "updated_date_time" = ?, "participant_ratings" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "trainings"."id" = ?  [["updated_date_time", 2017-01-30 12:24:01 UTC], ["participant_ratings", nil], ["updated_at", 2017-01-30 12:24:01 UTC], ["id", 3]]
   (2.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/trainings/3
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)

Comment: Got it. participant_ratings param is not inlcuded inside the training params hash.  So you could tweak the form to include raitings inside training object (name of the input should be training[participant_raitings]). Alternatively you can change the controller

Comment: sorry, you view is rather complicated, so it's easier to tweak the controller. i'm gonna post another answer

Comment: I just saw, that `participant_ratings` was not part of the `trainings`-hash so I adapted that and now I have the console log: `Unpermitted parameters: 3, 1, 2` for the submitted hash: `"participant_ratings"=>{"3"=>"5", "1"=>"", "2"=>""}`. These are the participant ids. How can I whitelist them? (sorry I have to write so much here as comments, but I have not enough reputation to start a chat)

Answer (score 0):

There's a an error in the controller. update method doesn't get the ratings param, so it goes unsaved. Here's the workaround:

```
class TrainingsController < BaseController
...
  def update
    @training = Training.find(params[:id])
    @training.updated_date_time = DateTime.now
    @training.participant_ratings = params[:participant_ratings]
    @training.assign_attributes(training_params)

    if @training.save
      flash[:notice] = t('flash.training.updated')
      redirect_to @training
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def training_params
      params.require(:training).permit(:village, :topic, :user_id, :start_time, :end_time, {:participant_ids => []})
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm bothering you so much! I changed everything in my controller to your suggestion above (added assign_attributes and changed update to save and removed ratings from training_params) and took participant_ratings out of the training-hash again but still the values are not saved... If I keep the ratings inside the training-hash and inside the trainings-params I get the console log: Unpermitted parameters: 3, 1, 2 for the submitted hash: "participant_ratings"=>{"3"=>"5", "1"=>"", "2"=>""}. These are the participant ids. Do you know how to whitelist them?

Comment: try to change this {:participant_ids => []} to simply :participant_ids